# Measurable Function Satisfying Condition

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory

Letting $\omega$ be a signed measure, how can I show that there is a measurable function $\rho$ satisfying both of 
$$ \mid \rho(x)|\;=\;1$$
$$d\omega\;=\;\rho \;d|\omega \mid\text{ ? }$$

Answer (score 1):

Use the Hahn decomposition theorem for signed measures, which gives two measurable sets $P,N$ for $\omega$ such that $\omega^+(E)=\omega(E\cap P)$ and $\omega^-=-\omega(E\cap N)$. Then

$$ \omega=\omega^+-\omega^- \quad \text{and} \quad \vert \omega \vert=\omega^++\omega^- $$

You can now define $\rho$ very naturally using $N$ and $P$.